# NSURLConnection crash on simultaneous failing connections IOS6.1 ARC Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new with IOS and I am still not sure if I've hit a bug, or I am doing something wrong. Although given the strange behaviour I get, I tend to think this is a bug in how IOS tries to reuse connections. I wonder if anyone knows about this and if there are workarounds.

Happens on IOS 6.1 ARC enabled, simulator. Even more strange is I can't get to crash it on the phone, so now I am wondering should I be afraid of this or not.

I am running multiple simultaneous http connections, once a connection finish or fails I am starting a new one. Until now I have 3 situations:

Case 1: the server exists and works, each request is successful, works.

Case 2: the server exists but won't listen on the given port, works.

Case 3: the server is offline (eg. the machine is down), will crash after 100-2000 requests.

**Edit:** modified the code according NicholasHart suggestion, the problem persists

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSURLRequest *request;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.178:8888/r.php"]
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                                timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSLog(@"starting %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    NSURLConnection *conn;

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {return nil;}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //[connection cancel]; //not needed, suggested by NicholasHart
    NSLog(@"ok %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //[connection cancel]; //not needed, suggested by NicholasHart
    NSLog(@"error %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
@end
```

For case 3 I have different crashes similar to:

```
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_retain:
0x49f98f0:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x49f98f4:  cmpl   $2147483647, 4(%eax)
0x49f98fb:  je     0x49f9910                 ; _dispatch_retain + 32
0x49f98fd:  addl   $4, %eax
0x49f9900:  movl   $1, %ecx
0x49f9905:  lock
0x49f9906:  xaddl  %ecx, (%eax)
0x49f9909:  incl   %ecx
0x49f990a:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
0x49f990c:  jg     0x49f9910                 ; _dispatch_retain + 32
0x49f990e:  ud2
0x49f9910:  ret
```

Comment: You didn't retain `NSURLConnection *conn`. The reference count of `conn` will be zero after the function returns. Try saving `conn` somewhere (e.g. in ViewController).

Comment: @HaiFengKao: An NSURLConnection retains itself until the connection is finished or has failed with an error.

Comment: you shouldn't need to cancel your connections in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` and `connection:didFailWithError:`.

Comment: @NicholasHart thanks for the tip, but changes nothing in this case.

Comment: Have you tried passing a copy of the request to the [NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest method?

Comment: I just tried your code on iPhone 6.1 Simulator with ARC enabled and it works great for me.

2013-08-22 22:00:18.020 TestTestTest[56248:c07] starting <NSThread: 0x714c810>{name = (null), num = 1}
2013-08-22 22:00:20.543 TestTestTest[56248:c07] ok <NSThread: 0x714c810>{name = (null), num = 1}
And so on for 100ds of lines

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se are you asking about passing a copy as not reusing the same NSURLRequest for each consecutive failed request? If yes, I tried, the result is the same.

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se it only fails in one specific scenario, try to access a nonexistent machine IP. If you read my post you will see that I am speaking about 3 cases, fails just in the last one.

Comment: I tried with a server with port 8888 closed, but not with an non-existent IP. (I guess you mean an IP that is totally dead and does not send any packets back when trying to connect?)

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se yes, just pick an ip in your local range which is not assigned to anyone for example.

Comment: behaves quite strange, the first 6 requests are failing after timeout, the next 50-100 fails immediately, then if the program is not crashing, again 6 requests stays the 10s timeout,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36055/discussion-between-www-jensolsson-se-and-sanyi)

Comment: Have you got the solution then please post.I am also stuck there.

Comment: Not really, other than I can't reproduce it on any physical device running IOS6.1, so I am building confidence that this is an emulator issue only.